# MySQL Custom calculate views

Tags: mysql, sql, database, view, calculated-columns

I am having difficulty trying to combine a set of queries I am using. I currently am having to execute multiple queries with different years and CID numbers. (CID is 1-5, Years are CurrentYear to CurrentYear-6)

Current SQL Statement:

```
SELECT 
1 as CID,
2015 as `Year`,
(   SELECT SUM( legacy_reports_payments.AmountPaid ) * -1 AS Payments FROM  legacy_reports_payments
    WHERE   DatePaid >= "2015-01-01 00:00:00"   AND DatePaid < "2015-02-01 00:00:00"
    AND CID = 1) As PaymentsJan,
(   SELECT SUM( legacy_reports_payments.AmountPaid ) * -1 AS Payments FROM  legacy_reports_payments
    WHERE   DatePaid >= "2015-02-01 00:00:00"   AND DatePaid < "2015-03-01 00:00:00"
    AND CID = 1) As PaymentsFeb,
(   SELECT SUM( legacy_reports_payments.AmountPaid ) * -1 AS Payments FROM  legacy_reports_payments
    WHERE   DatePaid >= "2015-03-01 00:00:00"   AND DatePaid < "2015-04-01 00:00:00"
    AND CID= 1) As PaymentsMar,
...
```

This returns:

```
CID  | Year | PaymentsJan | PaymentsFeb | ...
1    | 2015 | 3000.00     | 3000.00     | ...
```

I want to create a single view that can show all of the calculated information, instead of running several queries like the one above.
I would like to have the view look more like this:

```
CID   | Year | PaymentsJan | PaymentsFeb | ...
1     | 2015 | 3000.00     | 3000.00     | ...
2     | 2015 | 2000.00     | 2000.00     | ...
3     | 2015 | 5000.00     | 5000.00     | ...
1     | 2014 | 1000.00     | 3000.00     | ...
2     | 2014 | 3000.00     | 4000.00     | ...
3     | 2014 | 2000.00     | 5000.00     | ...
```

Can anyone provide any insight on the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could build a temporary table with the Years and CIDs you need and then join your query on that to do all of them at one.  That many sub queries will be slow, but better than doing each one manually.

```
create table #Dates
(
controlCID int
,controlYear varchar(4)
)

DECLARE @year int = YEAR( getDate() )
DECLARE @numYears int = 6
DECLARE @numCID int = 5
DECLARE @CIDcounter int

while (@numYears > 0)
BEGIN
    SET @CIDcounter = @numCID

    while (@CIDcounter > 0)
    BEGIN
        insert into #Dates values ( @CIDcounter,  (@year - @numYears + 1))

        SET @CIDcounter = @CIDcounter - 1
    END

    SET @numYears = @numYears -1
END

select controlCID
    ,controlYear
    --,(   SELECT SUM( legacy_reports_payments.AmountPaid ) * -1 AS Payments FROM  legacy_reports_payments
    --WHERE   p.DatePaid >= (controlYear+'-01-01 00:00:00')   AND p.DatePaid < (controlYear+'-02-01 00:00:00')
    --AND p.CID = controlCID) As PaymentsJan,   
    --etc and so on...
 from #Dates 
order by controlYear desc, controlCID 

drop table #Dates
```

Just use the year and CID from the table in the sub queries and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am not entirely certain how to run your query, as I am new to using stored procedures. When I try it it gives me an error on the DECLARE statements.  Any ideas?

Comment: (update). I got it to work. Thanks for your suggestion. I ended up using a stored function with your idea.